# インテグレーションテストで画面遷移後のwidgetがあるかどうかをテストするとエラーになる。

Tags: flutter, テスト, dart

*****やりたいこととできないこと*****
インテグレーションテストで画面遷移後にTextwidgetがあることを確認しようとしていますが、発見できていないというエラーが出ます。

#### エラー文

```
(The following exception is now available via WidgetTester.takeException:)
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
  Actual: _TextFinder:<zero widgets with text "ホーム" (ignoring offstage widgets)>
   Which: means none were found but one was expected

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
```

*****何を・どのように調べたのか*****
上記を解決するために、以下のキーワードで検索しました。

- flutter integration_test 画面遷移した時のwidgetを確認するやり方
- flutter integration_test How to check the widget at screen transition.

参考にした記事のURLは以下です。

[Flutterの新しいIntegration Testの導入](https://zenn.dev/sakusin/articles/4a3a5f0510438e)

---

#### ソースコード

```dart
// main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:integration_test_sample/first_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(    
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
              // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder));
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => FirstPage()
              ));
            }, child: Text('移動')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
// first_page.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ホーム"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('テスト'),         
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
// integration_test.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';

import 'package:integration_test_sample/main.dart' as app;

void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  group('group', () {
    testWidgets('start', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      app.main();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      expect(find.byType(FloatingActionButton), findsOneWidget);

      expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.text('1'), findsNothing);

      await tester.tap(find.byType(ElevatedButton));
      await tester.pump();
      
      expect(find.text('ホーム'), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.text('0'), findsNothing);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

integration_test.dart 内の `await tester.pump();` を `await tester.pumpAndSettle();` に変更します。

Comment: 正常に動作できました。very thx